# list all tables based on created date in hive

Tags: sql-server, hive

In `sql server` we use

```
select * 
from sys.tables 
where create_date = '2016-03-12'
```

to get all the tables metadata created on that date. Is there any equivalent of this in `hive`?

Comment: Possible solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16738516/hive-how-to-see-the-table-created-in-metastore?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in mysql metadata is stored in hive database

```
use hive;
select * from TBLS;
```

Comment: hi @Ravinder Karra , it is working but i am getting the exception "Communications link failure, The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server."
any idea of why i am not able to acess the metastore.

Comment: Restarting MySQL server. May be drivers are not upto date. This should be reviewed by System/DB Admin.